# ZF3 replacement of MutableCreationOptions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zf3

I wonder what is the replacement of `MutableCreationOptionsInterface` in Zend Framework 3 to provide the factories with the creation options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupidly enough from me to not realize that: the options are now passed to the `ContainerInterface` when using `$container->get(SomeClass, $options)`.